# Rspec method not found when using model subfolders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard

Hello i am receiving this error:

> spec/models/stores/persistent_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top
>   (required)>': undefined method`expect' for #
>   (NoMethodError)

Here is my setup. i have a class called **Store** located **inside app/models**

i have a class called **Stores::Temporary < Store** placed inside **app/models/stores**

I am trying to write tests for Temporary and they are failing with the error above

i have created **temporary_spec.rb** inside **spec/models/stores** and the code for it is the following:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe Stores::Temporary do

end
```

i am trying to write an expect to raise_error statement.

I have also tried **5.should == 5** which results with no available test being detected inside this file. I am using guard to autorun the tests, so changes in the files are being detected (works correctly) and tests are rerun but appear as blank.

Comment: Is the model name Store or Stores?

Comment: I would try `describe Store::Temporary do`.

Comment: No that doesnt work. says uninitialized constant Store::Temporary

Comment: Could you show the minimal full failing spec file? What you wrote up until now seems correct, so I am wondering how the rest of the spec looks like.

Comment: Its pretty much blank except one it-should containing a 5.should==5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after struggling with this for 2 hours i restarted the PC and it was working without changing anything... One of those stupid errors you just need to sorta sleep-over and retry.